# Suggestions for speeding up a dynamic programming solution to the Traveling Salesman Problem?

Tags: python, algorithm, traveling-salesman, np

I'm following an online course in which one of the assignments is to implement a dynamic programming algorithm to solve the Traveling Salesman Problem (TSP). My Python implementation works for small cases (~5 cities), but for the 'real' application of 25 cities it seems to be very slow. I'm looking for suggestions to speed up the algorithm.

The algorithm is described in the following excerpts:

[image]

[image]

[image]

The dynamic programming solution is also described at http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/travelling-salesman-problem-set-1/, where additional references are given.

The problem statement of the assignment is:

[image]

I've implemented the pseudocode using a pandas `DataFrame` object for the array `A`. Since sets are not hashable and can't be used as indices, I've instead used tuples, taking care to sort them in order to make them unique representations of sets. Here is the code along with several test cases of increasing size:

```
import functools
from itertools import combinations
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from cached_property import cached_property
import pytest


def powerset_list(s):
    '''Return a list of tuples representing all subsets of s'''
    return functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, [list(combinations(s, r)) for r in range(len(s)+1)])


class Graph(object):
    def __init__(self, edges):
        self.edges = edges

    @cached_property
    def nodes(self):
        _nodes = set()
        for edge in self.edges:
            u, v, weight = edge
            _nodes.add(u)
            _nodes.add(v)
        return list(_nodes)

    @cached_property
    def W(self):
        '''Matrix of edge weights'''
        n = len(self.nodes)
        w = np.full((n, n), np.inf)
        np.fill_diagonal(w, 0)
        w = pd.DataFrame(w, index=range(1, n+1), columns=range(1, n+1))
        for edge in self.edges:
            u, v, weight = edge
            w.set_value(u, v, weight)
            w.set_value(v, u, weight)
        return w

    def tsp(self):
        '''Solve the traveling salesman problem using a dynamic programming method'''
        n = len(self.nodes)
        sets = [(1,) + x for x in powerset_list(range(2, n+1))]
        A = pd.DataFrame(np.full((len(sets), n), np.inf), index=sets, columns=range(1, n+1))
        A.set_value((1,), 1, 0)
        for m in range(2, n+1):
            for S in [(1,) + perm for perm in combinations(range(2, n+1), m-1)]:
                for j in set(S) - set([1]):
                    S_min_j = tuple(sorted(set(S) - set([j])))
                    A.set_value(S, j, min(A.get_value(S_min_j, k) + self.W.get_value(k, j) for k in S_min_j))
        return min(A.get_value(tuple(range(1, n+1)), j) + self.W.get_value(j, 1) for j in range(2, n+1))


@pytest.fixture
def edges_geeksforgeeks():
    '''Edges from the example graph on http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/travelling-salesman-problem-set-1/'''
    return [(1, 2, 10), (1, 3, 15), (1, 4, 20), (2, 3, 35), (2, 4, 25), (3, 4, 30)]

def test_tsp(edges_geeksforgeeks):
    graph = Graph(edges_geeksforgeeks)
    min_cost = graph.tsp()
    assert min_cost == 80


def dist(coord1, coord2):
    return np.linalg.norm(np.array(coord1) - np.array(coord2))

def edges_from_coords(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        coords = [tuple(map(float, line.split())) for line in f.read().splitlines()[1:]]
    nodes = list(range(1, len(coords) + 1))
    coords = dict(zip(nodes, coords))
    return [(comb[0], comb[1], dist(coords[comb[0]], coords[comb[1]])) for comb in combinations(nodes, 2)]

@pytest.mark.parametrize("test_input, expected", [("Hulburd_1.txt", 10.24), ("Hulburd_2.txt", 12.36), ("Hulburd_3.txt", 14.00)])
def test_Hulburd(test_input, expected):
    '''Test data supplied by Eric Hulburd on the course forum'''
    edges = edges_from_coords(test_input)
    graph = Graph(edges)
    min_cost = graph.tsp()
    assert np.around(min_cost, decimals=2) == expected

@pytest.fixture
def edges_cities():
    return edges_from_coords('tsp.txt')

@pytest.mark.skip(reason="This takes too long to run")
def test_tsp_cities(edges_cities):
    graph = Graph(edges_cities)
    min_cost = graph.tsp()
    print("The minimum cost rounded down to the nearest integer is {}".format(int(np.floor(min_cost))))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pytest.main([__file__, "-s"])
```

The files used in the tests are [Hulburd_1.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_GPlDuPjd-UYThiYW9EYzZSTmc/view?usp=sharing), [Hulburd_2.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_GPlDuPjd-UdWdUZklWd1pabjg/view?usp=sharing), [Hulburd_3.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_GPlDuPjd-UWHV6Q191aGJzbUU/view?usp=sharing), and the main file for the actual assignment, [tsp.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_GPlDuPjd-UWHV6Q191aGJzbUU/view?usp=sharing). The problem is that the last (skipped) test involving `tsp.txt` takes too long to run.

How might I speed up the algorithm? On the course forum there are some saying they got it to run in ~3 minutes using bitmasks and parallelization; another suggestion was to simplify the indices of the array rather than using tuples.

Comment: More suited to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: I suppose Code Review is for programs that basically work, but my MacBook Pro with 16 GB of RAM can't run the last test (with 25 cities) because it runs out of memory. I suspect I have to make some fundamental improvements (e.g. using memoization instead of a bottom-up approach) to make this problem tractable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some ideas how to improve performance:

- instead of tuples use 32 bit ints to represent your subsets - this should be enough if you have no more than 32 cities
- on each step you need previously calculated values for subsets of size *m - 1* only (you don't have to store any values for subsets of size m-2, m-3 etc.) - this may vastly reduce your memory usage